# Cannot find include directive in Netbeans (For C programming

Tags: c, netbeans

I downloaded netbeans for C/C++. I followed every instructions and downloaded MinGW, and msys and added those to the environmental path. While trying to write a simple program it gives me warning that says `"cannot find include file <stdio.h>"`. It says that for every include directive i seem to use in the program.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Can't you just use a command line compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Turns our I did not install base package from MingW. After messing around with it a little bit, I got it working. Thanks everyone!